# Uploading from Windows to Amazon S3

Tags: windows, gratis, amazon

I am looking for a program that

- can upload a folder, its sub-folders and recursively, to an Amazon S3 bucket. It should be gratis (unlike [S3Express](http://www.s3express.com/)) at least for personal use
- can upload large files (say over 50 GB, unlike [S3Fox](http://www.s3fox.net/FAQs.aspx), which only allows file uploads/downloads upto 2GB).
- works on Windows

I don't want to have to go through some EC2 instances, but directly upload from Windows to Amazon S3.

Comment: I'm assuming there's a reason you don't want to use the web console? It says it can take files up to 5T each, and allows folders. If that works, I can post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Undo Thanks, actually that's a great suggestion I had missed the fact that it uploads folders recursively. Quite often though browser solutions don't support high load like 10k or 100k files. Any idea if the web console can absorb that amount of files? (S3Fox is web-based and can do over 100k, but I'm running some upload and don't want to mess it up, so I won't try 100k files right now with the web console in case it blows the RAM or something: I'll try tomorrow). In any case, yes please add as an answer, great ones are often the most obvious ones :-)